# How to decode a xmlrpc binary object in php?

Tags: php, python, xml-rpc, php4

I want to transfer some binary data over `xmlrpc`, from `python` on one end to `php` on the other end. The details are explained in [this python example](http://docs.python.org/2/library/xmlrpclib.html#binary-objects), especially the code on the server side handling the binary data:

```
from SimpleXMLRPCServer import SimpleXMLRPCServer
import xmlrpclib

def python_logo():
     with open("python_logo.jpg", "rb") as handle:
         return xmlrpclib.Binary(handle.read())

server = SimpleXMLRPCServer(("localhost", 8000))
print "Listening on port 8000..."
server.register_function(python_logo, 'python_logo')

server.serve_forever()
```

I would like to do almost exactly the same (except that I want to *store* the image on the server side), but in `PHP` (`PHP 4.4.9` to be precise). I know how to use a `xmlrpc` server in `PHP` (even `PHP 4`), but I do not know how to 'convert' the binary data, sent by the `Binary` object on the `python` side, back to a file.

Or to ask in a different way: What is the `PHP` equivalent to `python`s `Binary` object?